# SQL For Json path - auto inserted '\' if parameter content '/'

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

```
Declare @ContractCode nvarchar(100) = N'02/HĐLĐ-NGG';
Declare @DateStartWork date = '2020-06-01';
Declare @DeptID int = 2;
Declare @PositionID int = 4;
Declare @HRDecisionID int = 614

Select @ContractCode as ContractCode,
       @DateStartWork as DateStartWork,
       @DeptID as DeptID,
       @HRDecisionID as HRDecisionID
For Json Path
```

Then the Result =

```json
[{"ContractCode":"02\/HĐLĐ-NGG","DateStartWork":"2020-06-01","DeptID":2,"HRDecisionID":614}]
```

Instead of right value like:

```json
[{"ContractCode":"02/HĐLĐ-NGG","DateStartWork":"2020-06-01","DeptID":2,"HRDecisionID":614}]
```

So please help me to answer Why it automatically inserted \ before '/' into ContractCode.

Comment: The `\ ` is an escape character. Any *good* JSON parser will read the value `"02\/HĐLĐ-NGG"` as `"02/HĐLĐ-NGG"`.

Comment: Because [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)? [ECMA-404](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf) lists the solidus character as something to be escaped. See _Section 9: String_

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: could you suggest any solution for this trouble?

Comment: What's the trouble? Why should the `\\` *not* be there, it's in the spec?

Comment: It's expected and correct behavior. The trouble is you think it's wrong.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning and Larnu, Charlieface: Thanks all of you for your info; I'v affraid it can make some trouble to display.

Comment: "it can make some trouble to display" what trouble? What issue are you having?

Comment: @Charlieface: I've affraid; but after check I found that is OK. Thanks all of you.